# Is there a method reference available for throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, method-reference

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Runnable exceptionHandler = () -> throw new RuntimeException();
```

Is there a way to write it more concise, available now, or maybe available in future Java releases? I'd expect something along the lines of:

```
Runnable exceptionHandler = RuntimeException::throw;
```

For extra information, I intend to use this code for a method in which exceptional situations can occur, but not always need there be a `RuntimeException` thrown. I want to give callers the freedom to do whatever they want at the point the exceptional situation occurs.

As it seems to me, this is not possible with Java 8, has this been discussed and is there any reason this is not possible?

Comment: Directed at who ever wants to close this. I do not see how this would be primarily opinion-based. As there are always **reasons** behind why a feature may not be in a language, I also might be overlooking functionality, and the Java Expert Group uses mailing list conversations, and in there this might have been brought up.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice; you can write utility methods which would work for any `Consumer` etc but the exception would have to be unchecked. The fact that exceptions don't propagate "outside" a stream (and as such cannot be caught/dealt with outside of streams) is particularly infuriating at times

Comment: @skiwi Of course there are reasons. The question is whether those reasons are accessible here. Unless someone in the JSR expert group shows up, which isn't likely, and unless they divulge the reason, which may not even be legally possible, the answer is 'no', and the result is only going to be more or less uninformed opinion.

Answer (score 2):

`Exception::throw` is not valid and I can't find any related discussions in the mailing lists.

However if your intent is: "*to give callers the freedom to do whatever they want at the point the exceptional situation occurs*", you could use a design similar to `CompletableFuture` and write something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> somethingThatMayThrow())
                     .exceptionally(t -> { t.printStackTrace(); return null; });
}

private static void somethingThatMayThrow() throws RuntimeException {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

That only works with unchecked exception though.

Comment: I didn't know `CompletableFuture`! "Pity" it only works for `Runnable`s though

Comment: @Fge It's very handy indeed. You can also `supplyAsync(supplier)`.